# How to query 180 days old user from repository using Spring Data JPA @Query annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to retrieve all the user from User, who are 180 days older using Spring Data JPA @Query Annotation. Here is the query..

```
@Query("select user from User user where datediff(?1,user.createdTime)>=180")
List<User> findByCreatedDateMoreThanSixMonths(Date currentDate);
```

following is the calling Code.

```
List<User> userList = userRepository.findByCreatedDateMoreThanSixMonths(new Date());
```

Is this the way or am i missing anything? bcz doing so is not giving expected result.

Comment: Should you not be doing a date comparison here? If `user.createdTime` is also a `Date` object it won't be able to query an integer `180`...

Comment: I think dateDiff() will compare dates and return number of days as integer. isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your Repository Bro:-

1.If you want to use native MySQL Date Method:-

```
@Query("select user from User user where datediff(curdate(),user.createdTime)>=180")
List<User> findByCreatedDateMoreThanSixMonths();
```

2.If you want to pass Date of your own:-

```
@Query("select user from User user where datediff(currentDate,user.createdTime)>=180")
List<User> findByCreatedDateMoreThanSixMonths(@Param("currentDate") Date currentDate);
```

If you are using different type of database, you can still find the same configurations for it.

Comment: **Warning:** this solution ties a repository to a specific DB (MySQL), so think twice before applying. For me, it doesn't work because I need to share the same repository between MySQL (main) and H2 (test) databases. MySQL accepts two parameters in `datediff()` and H2 accepts three parameters in `datediff()` which makes them incompatible.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `JPA named query`:

```
List<User> findByCreatedAtBefore(Date expiryDate);

public void performLookUp(){

   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   Date today = cal.getTime();
   cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -180);
   Date daysAgo180 = cal.getTime();

   MyUserRepository.findByCreatedAtBefore(daysAgo180);
}
```

If you want to check for 6 months back, you can `add(Calendar.MONTH, -6)`